# Gaussian Distribution Transform, plotting with Histogram

Tags: c

I have a problem where I need to generate 1000 gaussian distributed numbers between -3 & 3, and then plot them on a histogram. Here's my code so far:

globally declared arrays:

```
double s, u[1000], v[1000], z;
  int gauss[1000];
  double transformed[2000];

      void run(){
      int max;
      while(1){
      srand( time(NULL) );
      generateec();
      transform();
      max = findMax();
      plot( max );
      getchar();  
      }}

void plot ( int max )
{

   int j, s;

   for ( j=0; j<maxPlus; j++ )
   {
   printf("%3d (%5d) > ", j, gauss[j] );
   for ( s=0; s<transformed[j]*barWidth/max; s++ ) printf("|");

   printf("\n");
    }
 }
int findMax()
  {
   int j;
   int max = transformed[0];

  for ( j=1; j < maxPlus; j++ )
  {
  if ( transformed[j] > max )
  max = transformed[j];
 }

 return max;
 }
void generateec(){
srand( time(NULL) );
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
 {
u[i] = (double)rand()/(double)(RAND_MAX);
v[i] = (double)rand()/(double)(RAND_MAX);
 }
}

void transform(){
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
{
    if( (u[i] + v[i]) > 0){
    s = (u[i]*u[i])+(v[i]*v[i]);
    transformed[2*i] = sqrt(-2.0 * log(u[i])) * cos(2 * pi * v[i]); 
    transformed[2*i+1] = sqrt(-2.0 * log(u[i])) * sin(2 * pi * v[i]);  
    }

}

printf("%d %d %d \n", transformed[0], transformed[500], transformed[600]);

   }
```

I call the run function from the main function, generate the numbers, transform them, and then plot them. For some reason, I'm getting all zeroes when I run it. I'm not sure why, any help would be awesome,

Thanks guys!

Comment: Do you mean Gaussian distributed numbers with standard deviation=3 or variance=3, instead of between [-3,3]?

Comment: From what I understand, deviation = 3.

Comment: There is still something missing. The array gauss[] is never set in the above code.

Comment: FYI, if this is something you need to do a lot (not just a one-off or an exercise), take a look at my public domain library: http://github.com/lcrocker/ojrandlib . It will produce normally-distributed doubles using the fast Ziggurat algorithm, and with 54 bits of accuracy (rand() might be giving you as few as 15).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried completing your code with the missing declarations and the Box-Muller transform seems to be working.

I believe that your problem is somewhere in the declarations of the arrays, which you left out from the posted code.

Below is the modified program: (compiled with `gcc -std=c99 -lm boxmuller.c -o boxmuller`)

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <time.h>
 #include <math.h>

 double v[1000];
 double u[1000];
 double transformed[2000];


 void generateec() {
   //srand( time(NULL) );
   for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
   {
     u[i] = (double)rand()/(double)(RAND_MAX);
     v[i] = (double)rand()/(double)(RAND_MAX);
   }
 }

 void transform(){
   static const double pi = 3.14159265358979323846;
   for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
   {
     if( (u[i] + v[i]) > 0) {
       double s = (u[i]*u[i])+(v[i]*v[i]);
       transformed[2*i] = sqrt(-2.0 * log(u[i])) * cos(2 * pi * v[i]);·
       transformed[2*i+1] = sqrt(-2.0 * log(u[i])) * sin(2 * pi * v[i]);··
     }
   }
   printf("%f %f %f \n", transformed[0], transformed[500], transformed[600]);
 }

 void run(){
   int max;
   srand( time(NULL) );
   while(1){
     generateec();
     transform();
     //max = findMax();
     //plot( max );
     getchar();··
   }
 }

 int main(int argc, char** argv) {
     run();
     return 0;
 }
```

Some additional points:

- You probably don't want to reinitialize the random number generator with the timer on every iteration.
- You print floats as if they were integers.
- The transform generates numbers with a N(0,1) distribution, i.e. Gaussian with mean = 0, standard deviation = 1.

Comment: Thank you! I messed around with it, and got it working. My plot function was also a little messed up.

Comment: Added a note about the standard deviation of the generated numbers. To get the wanted distribution you'll have to multiply by 3.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still betting its the arrays.  If you take a look at u and v, they're not declared globally.  Where are t hey declared?  What are they allocated to?

Comment: Sorry about that, forgot to add the declarations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume `u`, `v`, `transformed` are properly initialized as (otherwise you'd get a crash).  Double-check that, then this is your/a problem:

```
printf("%d %d %d \n", transformed[0], transformed[500], transformed[600]);
```

It should be

```
printf("%f %f %f \n", transformed[0], transformed[500], transformed[600]);
```

And of course the arrays should be declared as `double` or `float`.  Truncation could well be the culprit here.

Comment: That line is more of a check to see that they are being transformed properly, it doesn't actually serve a purpose with the histogram.

Comment: @MichaelRupert How are `u` and `v` declared?

Comment: Also, how is `findMax()` implemented?

Comment: line with u and v added. findmax also added.

Comment: @MichaelRupert At this point I'm guessing the problem is with your plotting code, the above looks functional.

Comment: @MichaelRupert Mkay and now how does `gauss` get defined?